# Minecraft Port Forwarding not working Windows

Tags: windows-10, port-forwarding, minecraft

i`m very Confused.
Port Forwarding for my Minecraft Server don't Work. My Router is a Huawei B311-221 and I use Windows 10 Pro for hosting it. At every thing i tried check for open ports but no results!
Connecting on my home network works great.

What can i do now?
What I tried:

- [Enabled Port Forwarding (Called Virtual Server on Router Config Page)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRRqj.png)
- [Enabled Special Applications on CP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNAoC.png)
- Config Firewall for the 25565 Port
- Config Firewall for all Java Stuff
- Disabled Firewall

ipconfig Output

```
Windows-IP-Konfiguration


Ethernet-Adapter Ethernet 2:

   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
   Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse  . : fe80::84d2:af3d:7f4c:5287%15
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . :

Drahtlos-LAN-Adapter LAN-Verbindung* 9:

   Medienstatus. . . . . . . . . . . : Medium getrennt
   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:

Drahtlos-LAN-Adapter LAN-Verbindung* 11:

   Medienstatus. . . . . . . . . . . : Medium getrennt
   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:

Drahtlos-LAN-Adapter WLAN:

   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
   IPv6-Adresse. . . . . . . . . . . : fdd8:8adc:64af:d500:4196:1ed4:73d6:d773
   Temporäre IPv6-Adresse. . . . . . : fdd8:8adc:64af:d500:a958:5879:badc:a6f2
   Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse  . : fe80::4196:1ed4:73d6:d773%8
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.175
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: Your ISP probably uses Carrier-Grade NAT. You won't be able to do conventional port forwarding if that is the case. You can tell for sure by looking at your router's configuration page, and looking at your WAN IP address. If it starts with 100, 192, 10, 172.16, etc. then your ISP is using Carrier-Grade NAT and it won't work. You'll need to use a tunneling service or rent a server hosted elsewhere.

Comment: You are right, thanks for your help! Can you recommend a tunneling service to me? Should be free because it is only temporary and for test purposes. @SamForbis

Comment: LogMeIn Hamachi is good if you're just looking to open a server to friends (not public). Take a look at [this page](https://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm) for some details about other alternatives. Note that using a tunnel/VPN will make the connection laggier than it would otherwise be.

Comment: Can someone agree this?

Comment: Agree is a better word for it, I`m not shure if there is really no way to Port Forward, look at Antonios P. Post. But with LogMeIn Hamachi everyone need it or? I need a solution which only I need addicitional Software and no other. With [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) it works fine for TCP but not for UDP so i cannot use it. Should be like that but supporting UDP too or only that!

Comment: I'm fairly certain Minecraft Java edition only uses TCP. As I mentioned, if your ISP uses CGNAT there is *no* way for conventional port forwarding to work. Port forwarding only works if you have a public IP address assigned directly to your router, and CGNAT fundamentally prevents that from happening. You may have some success with IPv6 if your ISP uses that, but your router may not support it. Everyone who wants to connect would need Hamachi if you wanted to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You are a little unclear about your port forwarding configuration. I understand that you are doing it client-side (in Windows). Please correct me if that is not the case. However, Port Forwarding will need to be done one the router, modem, etc. that provides internet to your location. Doing it in Windows is not going to work. From my experience, you don't need to do a firewall, but it doesn't hurt. Go into your router, and head over to the port-forwarding section of the interface. For me, it's *Virtual Server/Port Forwarding* under *WAN*. Add a new entry with the following settings:

- Service Name: Whatever name you want to give it.
- Protocol: TCP/UPD/***BOTH***
- External Port: 25565
- Internal Port: 25565
- Internal IP Address: ***LOCAL*** IP of your machine
- Source IP: Leave blank

Below is a screenshot of the configuration on my router:
[Minecraft Java Port Forwarding Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YR7SZ.png)

An edit so that the image shows up inline would be very appreciated. I don't have enough REP yet to do that.

Comment: Sorry for beegin unclearly i`ve meant the Minecraft Runs on Windows.
I had already done it on the router/modem Config Page, added as Links to the Question.
 
[Server Configuration](https://i.imgur.com/bDG7bVT.png)

Comment: Are you accessing the server in you LAN?

Comment: I can't comment there yet, but that IP address that @Sam Forbis is talking is your LOCAL IP, and not public. You shouldn't need to use a tunneling service. What your PUBLIC IP *PREFIX*. I don't want to leak your full IP. E.x: 97.XXX.XXX.XXX

Comment: Hm, i don't know shure. I can connect to it at the pc I'm hosting it. How can i test it?
I haven't installed minecraft on any other pc in my LAN

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=what%27s+my+ip&oq=what%27s+my+ip&aqs=chrome.0.69i59.2714j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8. This will show your IP at the top of the search

Comment: Then, what you can do is test if the port is open using [this](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) tool and using *25565* as the port and your public IP as the remote address.

Comment: I`ve done this but that always says that the Port is Closed :/

Comment: What can i do now?

Comment: is your minecraft server running? If it is, then the port hasn't been forwarded. Try setting the protocol to only TCP just to rule out some theories. Minecraft Java only uses TCP/25565

Comment: what is the first set of numbers in your IP address? This is important to know if you have CGNET.

Comment: Yes it`s running, have tried it but also dont work.
Die First numbers are 91, hope thats enough

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks. it seems that you are not under the control of a CGNAT (great!), but that still does not explain why that is not working. As I do not have this router on hand, I am unable to test and configure. I am assuming the test from opensignal came back *as port not open*. I would just try to ping the server remotely using the public IP. If that works, then I don't know what the cause would be. If that fails, then it might be connectivity. Unless I thin of something, that is all the help I can provide you with. I wish you the best of luck with your project.

Comment: I would try accessing your minecraft server both using ```[public-ip]``` and ```[public-ip]:25565``` with ```[public-ip]``` being your public IP at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm behind a CGNat so there is no way to open a Port.
Easy to find out: If your Modem run's with a SIM so it uses 4G/5G which means that`s CGNat